# How change namespace of Soap ns2 message in %SOAP.Webclient

Tags: intersystems-ensemble, intersystems-iris

I've created a soap client connection using the wizard of Atelier and it has created all messages (request and response) and the business operation object.

This soap connection will be used to connecto with other SOAP Webservices (changing the URL) but the namespace of the envelope will be different for the destination.

I've done a change into the Soap class to add my namespace for the envelope

```
Property Namespace As %String
Parameter SETTINGS = "Namespace:Basic";
Method methodFind(idEspecialist As %String(REQUIRED=1), actList As %ListOfObjects(Myapp.ns2.actType") [ Final, ProcedureBlock = 1, SoapBindingStyle = document, SoapBodyUse = literal, WebMethod ]
 {
 Quit ..WebMethod("methodFind").Invoke($this,..Namespace_"/methodFind",.idEspecialist,.actList)
 }
```

and it works, only I have to create a new BO item in the producction and set the namespace for the destination.

But the ns.actType has the property namespace in the definition (as I said, this object has been created with the wizard of Atelire (SOAP)) and it is used for all BO.

```
/// created from: http://mywsservice.salutic.org/EspecialistWS?wsdl=EspecialistWSSoap.wsdl
Class Myapp.ns2.actoType Extends (%SerialObject, %XML.Adaptor) [ ProcedureBlock ]
{

Parameter ELEMENTQUALIFIED = 1;

Parameter NAMESPACE = "http://mywsservice.salutic.org/";

Parameter XMLNAME = "actType";

Parameter XMLSEQUENCE = 1;

Property ActCode As %String(MAXLEN = "", XMLNAME = "ActCode") [ Required ];

Property description As  %String(MAXLEN = "", XMLNAME = "description") [ Required ];
......
......
}
```

So, when the invokeClient method is creating the SOAP Envelope, it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:s='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <methodFind xmlns="http://customer.namespace.org/">
        <idEspecialist xsi:type="s:string">TAC</idEspecialist>
        <actList>
            <act xmlns:s01="http://mywsservice.salutic.org/" xsi:type="s01:actoType">
                <ActCode xsi:type="s:string">1032001</ActCode>
                <description xsi:type="s:string">Torax</description>
            </act>
        </actList>
    </methodFind>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Is there any way to change the namespace of the node programmatically?

Best regards,
Kurro López

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your code to give specifics but when the client object is created it should have a %SOAP.SessionHeader that has a NAMESPACE property.  It should be attached to the HeadersOut property of the SOAP.WebClient

This is all from memory though so you need to check.